# Changing the value of a variable based on output of manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I'm trying to use the output value of a manipulate to define a variable that will be used for a calculation.  I've created a minimal example of what I'm trying to do.  In this case, I'd like to use the output value of *test* to define the variable *testVar* so that I can use testVar in defining *testCal*.

```
    Manipulate[
 testVar = If[test == "b", 2 , 5];
 testCalc = testVar*2;
 Text[testCalc],
 {{test, "a", "Test Manipulate"}, {Style["a", 14, Red], 
   Style["b", 14, Blue], Style["c", 14, Green]}}
 ]
```

When I run this code, I get the correct output, which seems promising.

[image]

Unfortunately, when I click on any of the options, *testCalc* doesn't properly evaluate.  I've tried using Dynamic in a few places, but haven't been able to figure out how to get *testCalc* to properly evaluate when I click on the different options for Test Manipulate.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Manipulate[
 testVar = If[SameQ[test, Style["b", 14, Blue]], 2, 5];
 testCalc = testVar*2;
 Text[testCalc],

 (*controls below*)

 {{test, "a", "Test Manipulate"}, {Style["a", 14, Red], 
   Style["b", 14, Blue], Style["c", 14, Green]}},

 TrackedSymbols :> {test}
 ]
```

First, your `test` is not string, it is `Style["b", 14, Blue]`, second use `SameQ[]` and not `==`. Also notice that your control variable `test` is not `String`. it is actually a `Style`. So you can not compare `String` with a `Style`.

When you do `"a" == Head[Style["a", 14, Red]]` Mathematica does not return `True` nor `False`. It returns the same expression. That is why you were hitting the 3rd argument of `If` which you did not have.

[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Thanks!